# ActiveAdmin + CanCanCan errors with : protected method `authorize!' called for <Every ActiveAdmin Controller>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, cancancan

I'm having some trouble getting ActiveAdmin to work with CanCanCan. I'm using CanCanCan version 1.9.2 and ActiveAdmin version 1.0.0.pre in a Rails 4 app. After setting up my ability class and enabling authorization checks in the rest of my app by adding `load_and_authorize_resource` and `check_authorization` to my ApplicationController, I get the error

`protected method 'authorize!' called for #<Activeadmin::<SomeControler>> (NoMethodError)`

After some searching, I ran into [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2077) this GitHub issue that looks exactly like the problem I'm having. The solution does not work at all for me, however. In config/initializers/active_admin.rb I have, among other things:

`...
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
...`

I have also ensured that I have no references to `controller.authorize_resource` in any ActiveAdmin controller, yet I still get the `protected method authorize! ...` error when I try to access any ActiveAdmin resources from my integration tests.

After some more trial and error and more searching, I discovered that calling `load_and_authorize_resource` from ApplicationController was not recommended, and that setting ActiveAdmin's authorization_adapter to CanCanAdapter as I did above should automatically enable CanCanCan's authorization checks in ActiveAdmin, but `check_authorization` fails because the resource was not authorized for every ActiveAdmin controller when `load_and_authorize_resource` is removed from ApplicationController.

So what is the correct way to enable CanCanCan's authorization checks for my ActiveAdmin controllers? How should I integrate CanCanCan and ActiveAdmin so that non admin users can't access any ActiveAdmin resources?

I also posted [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/activeadmin/6FMZziK_dcI) question to the ActiveAdmin mailing list but got no responses. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging through the code, I've figured out what's happening. ActiveAdmin and it's CanCanAdapter is not yet compatible with CanCanCan's `check_authorization` method. That method relies on an `@_authorized` instance variable being set on the controller by the authorization method, but ActiveAdmin's authorization does not set this variable. So, even though ActiveAdmin IS performing the authorization, `check_authorization` always fails because ActiveAdmin is not setting this instance variable. I've reported the issue, but the workaround for now is to add an `unless:` clause to `check_authorization` that matches all ActiveAdmin controllers. This stops `check_authorization` from running for these controllers, but, as long as CanCanAdapter is enabled, ActiveAdmin IS still performing the proper authorizations before responding with the resource.

Here is the workaround that I've added to my ApplicationController until the issue is fixed, if it ever will be:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  check_authorization unless: :activeadmin_resource?
  ...
  private

  def activeadmin_resource?
    self.class.ancestors.include? ActiveAdmin::BaseController
  end
end
```

Comment: This is working well for me and removes unauthorized abilities from the ActiveAdmin interface.  Removing load_and_authorize_resource from ApplicationController and adding the code suggested here did the trick.

Comment: Thank you! I had hard times with this very same issue, when I had to upgrade from Rails 3.2 (ActiveAdmin 0.5.1) to Rails 5.0 (ActiveAdmin 1.0.0pre4). I reported this issue in ActiveAdmin's issue tracker: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4599

Answer (score 3):

This no longer works with Rails 5.